# CSSMatrix multiplication

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, webkit

According to [WebKitCSSMatrix documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AudioVideo/Reference/WebKitCSSMatrixClassReference/WebKitCSSMatrix/WebKitCSSMatrix.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/WebKitCSSMatrix/multiply), multiply() function "Returns the result of multiplying this matrix by a given matrix that is on the right.". So

`a.multiply(b)` must be equal to `a b` in math notation.

But it seems that `a.multiply(b)` is indeed equal to `b a`; the result is equal to the product when the given matrix at the left.

**For an example:**

Let a:

```
 2, -2,  5,  0
-1,  0, 12,  0
 3,  1, -2,  0
 0,  0,  0,  1
```

and B:

```
 1,  4,  3,  0
 3,  1,  5,  0
 3,  4,  3,  0
 0,  0,  0,  1
```

Using [this tool](http://wims.unice.fr/wims/wims.cg?module=tool/linear/matmult) the product of `a b` is

```
c = a b:

11, 26, 11,  0
35, 44, 33,  0
0,   5,  8,  0
0,   0,  0,  1
```

In JavaScript:

```
a = new WebKitCSSMatrix("matrix3d(2,-2,5,0,  -1,0,12,0,  3,1,-2,0,  0,0,0,1)")
b = new WebKitCSSMatrix("matrix3d(1,4,3,0,  3,1,5,0,  3,4,3,0,  0,0,0,1)");
```

and `a.multiply(b)` is:

```
7,   1,  47,  0
20, -1,  17,  0
11, -3,  57,  0
0,   0,   0,  1
```

but actually `b.multiply(a)` is matrix `c`.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your observation but the spec is also correct in its description.  What you have to observe is that matrices defined in the CSS spec are column-major where as most math books will tackle matrices in row-major format.  Try converting it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is "[in general not commutative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication)" which means that a.multiply(b) is generally not going to be the same as b.multiply(a).